# How can I use function return val as left val in Python?

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I want to make the below c code work in Python, how can I make it?

```
// low level
typedef int* (*func)(int);

// high level
int a[2];

// high level
int* foo(int i) { return &a[i]; }

// low level
void goo(func f) {
  int i = 0;
  for(; i < 2; ++i) *f(i) = 7;
}

int main(void)
{
  goo(foo);
  return 0;
}
```

When I write a low level function such s goo I want to use the pointer returned by high level user-defined function foo.

It is really easy in c and I want to make it in Python, How?
Thanks!!

Comment: "pointer" Not happening.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to ask *why* you want this.  If I saw code like this in C, I would strongly discourage the author from writing this: it looks like an intentionally way to obfuscate.

`f`'s sole purpose seems to be to allow mutation on `a`.  In that case, the function signature is weird.  Why not:

```
typedef void (*func)(int, int);
```

which takes in the index as well as the value you're trying to set?  In this case, we can even give this signature a good name, a "setter".

```
typedef void (*setter)(int, int);
```

With this, the C code is simple and direct,

```
void foo(int i, int val) { a[i] = val; }

void goo(setter f) {
  int i = 0;
  for(; i < 2; ++i) f(i, 7);
}
```

and the Python translation of this is also straightforward.

If you truly needed something like this, just capture the idea of mutation in something callable, and return that.  That's really what a pointer is, right?  For example:

```
a = [0, 0]

def foo(i):
    def mutate(v):
        a[i] = v
    return mutate

def goo(f):
    for i in range(2):
        f(i)(7)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    goo(foo)
    print a
```

A pointer isn't a pointer because it's physically represented by a "star" operator.  It's a pointer because we can refer and mutate it.  We can do that with just plain functions:

```
a = [4, 17]

def foo(i):
    def ref():
        return a[i]
    def mutate(v):
        a[i] = v
    return { 'ref' : ref, 'mutate' : mutate }

def goo(f):
    for i in range(2):
        ptr = f(i)
        print "at", i, "I see", ptr['ref']() 
        ptr['mutate'](7)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    goo(foo)
    print a
```

If we wanted to make it prettier, I suppose we could use classes.

```
a = [4, 17]

def foo(i):
    class Ptr(object):  
        def __init__(self): pass
        def ref(self):
            return a[i]
        def set(self, v):
            a[i] = v
    return Ptr()

def goo(f):
    for i in range(2):
        ptr = f(i)
        print "at", i, "I see", ptr.ref() 
        ptr.set(7)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    goo(foo)
    print a
```

But again, I would not just blindly use this: I'd rather see real code and see what you're trying to do.

Comment: because I don't know which index way can high level want in a, for example a[i,:], another a[:,i] suppose a is a 2d array.

Comment: Ok, answer generalized to show you how to express the essential idea of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Like others, I really don't see why you'd want this. But you could return a function that changes something.

Here's a translation of your code:

```
# high level
a [ 0, 0 ]

# high level
def foo(i):
    def change(n): a[i] = n
    return change

# low level
def goo(f):
   for i in range(2):
        f(i)(7)

goo(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no pointers in Python, or arrays for that matter.  Rather than fill in a list created someplace else, the usual Python idiom is to return a modified copy of the list.

However, Python does let you define your own object types, and overload what the operators mean.  So, while there is no unary * to overload in Python, you could overload what p[x] means, and p[0] means the same thing as *p in C.

Read here about what you can do with Python classes.  "New-style" classes are the best choice in Python 2.x and become the *only* choice in Python 3.
http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

As for passing a function to a Python function, just pass the name, without parentheses:

```
import math
def f1(x):
    return 2*x + 1

def sumf( func, vals ):
    return sum( func(x) for x in vals );

print sumf( f1, (1, 2, 3) )
print sumf( math.cos, [0, math.pi/2, math.pi] )
```

As you can see, library functions pass just as well as user defined ones.

Comment: I can only return a list(such as l = [1, 2]) as a ref to make it.